# How to find individual elements in a table view using autoit library of RobotFramework

Tags: outlook, robotframework, autoit

I'm using RobotFramework - AutoIt Library on Windows 10. My test application is MS Outlook. I want to click on an individual email (first or second or third or depending upon subject etc.) but I'm not able to because all the emails are in a table view and have one control id. I am looking for some individual id so that I can click on an individual item.

Here is the Outlook ids I get it using the AutoIt tool:

[Outlook id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPyCF.png)

How can I get individual ids or may be is there any work around?

Comment: Is your real problem how to automate outlook, or is your real problem how to read email from a specific email account?

Comment: My real problem is how to automate outlook and reading email is a part of it.

Comment: See OutlookEX UDF to automate outlook. https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/files/file/381-outlookex/